# If $\zeta<\omega_\zeta$ how is it possible there exist a cardinal $\alpha$ such that $\alpha=\aleph_\alpha$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Since using transfinite induction it's possible to demonstrate that for every ordinals $\zeta$, we have $\zeta<\omega_\zeta$, it seems that it isn't possible that there exist an infinite cardinal $\alpha$ (which can also be an initial ordinal) such that $\alpha=\aleph_\alpha$: infact if it's true, it results that there exist two different ordinal ($\alpha$ and $\omega_\alpha$) such that $\alpha<\omega_\alpha$ and $|\alpha|=|\omega_\alpha|$, so while $\omega_\alpha$ is an initial ordinal it must be $\alpha=\omega_\alpha$ and for the hypothesis this is impossible.

Comment: "... it's possible to demonstrate that for every ordinals $\zeta$ it's $\zeta < \omega_\zeta$", are you sure about this?

Comment: $0<\omega=\omega_0$;

$\alpha<\omega_\alpha<\omega_{\alpha+1}\Rightarrow\alpha+1\le\omega_\alpha<\omega_{\alpha+1}$;

$\beta<\omega_\beta\Rightarrow\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}\beta<\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}\omega_\beta\Rightarrow\alpha<\omega_\alpha$.

Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Double check your limit stage

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand: could you explain better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Since using transfinite induction it's possible to demonstrate that for every ordinals $\zeta$ it's $\zeta<\omega_\zeta$

No, it isn't. What you *can* show is that $\zeta\le\omega_\zeta$ for all $\zeta$, but that's quite different.

Any attempted inductive argument to prove the claim above will run into trouble at limit stages. For example, just because $\alpha_n<\beta_n$ for all $n<\omega$ does *not* mean that $\sup\{\alpha_n:n\in\omega\}<\sup\{\beta_n:n\in\omega\}$; consider $$\alpha_n=n, \beta_n=2n.$$

So when $\lambda$ is a limt you **cannot** argue that $$\forall\zeta<\lambda(\omega_\zeta<\omega_\lambda)\quad\implies\quad\lambda<\omega_\lambda.$$

Comment: Okay, I understood. Anyway using transfinite induction is it possible to demonstrate that $\alpha\le\omega_\alpha$?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Yes, it is - that is the correct inequality.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

What you say is simply false. It's true that for some $\xi$ it is true that $\xi<\omega_\xi$, but that's not true for all ordinals.

Indeed, in a technical sense, one can say that a typical ordinal is of the form $\xi=\omega_\xi$.

Comment: So it's uncorrect to prove to demonstrate by transfinite induction that $\alpha<\omega_\alpha$. Anyway using transfinite induction I see that $\alpha<\omega_\alpha$: pheraps it false that using transfinite induction it's possible demonstrate that $\alpha<\omega_\alpha$?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Your limit step is wrong, just because $\alpha_i<\beta_i$ for every $i$, it does not mean $\bigcup \alpha_i<\bigcup\beta_i$. Try $\alpha_i=i$ and $\beta_i=i+1$ for $i<\omega$. What you get at limit stage is $\alpha\leq\omega_\alpha$, so you can prove by transfinite induction that $\alpha\leq\omega_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$, but the strict inequality is just wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by the claim that "typical ordinals" satisfy $\xi = \omega_\xi$?

Comment: I don't know if that's what Asaf meant, but ordinals satisfying $\xi=\omega_\xi$ are a club in $\mathsf{Ord}$, so they are a very big subclass of the ordinals in some sense

Comment: @MeesdeVries: The class of ordinals satisfying $\xi=\omega_\xi$ is a closed and unbounded class, which in some sense means that "almost every ordinal" is in that class.

Comment: That was very close, there's only one second of difference between our two comments! @Asaf

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti: Yes, I was on the bus, and my text kept jumping between lines.

Comment: @Asaf Excuses...

Comment: @Andrés: Well, reasons. :-P